# How can I make a Java method for simplifying a fraction?

Tags: java, simplify, fractions

I have written a Fraction class, and am having trouble with the simplification.

When I make the Fraction object, everything works fine, i just think my logic is messy with the simplification.

(num and den are private variables in the class for numerator and denominator respectively)

Here are my GCD and Simplify methods:

```
/**
 * Returns the absolute value of the greatest common divisor of this
 * fraction's numerator and denominator. If the numerator or denominator is
 * zero, this method returns 0. This method always returns either a positive
 * integer, or zero.
 * 
 * @return Returns the greatest common denominator
 */
private int gcd() {
    int s;
    if (num > den)
        s = den;
    else
        s = num;
    for (int i = s; i > 0; i--) {
        if ((num % i == 0) && (den % i == 0))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Changes this fraction's numerator and denominator to "lowest terms"
 * (sometimes referred to as a "common fraction"), by dividing the numerator
 * and denominator by their greatest common divisor. This includes fixing
 * the signs. For example, if a fraction is 24/-18, this method will change
 * it to -4/3. If the numerator or denominator of the fraction is zero, no
 * change is made.
 */
public void simplify() {

    if (isZero() == false) {// Making sure num or den is not zero.
        this.fixSigns(); // Fix signs first

        if (gcd() > 1) {
            this.num = num / gcd();
            this.den = num / gcd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a problem with this code? It doesn't give the good results? What do you expect and what is happening?

Comment: Hey @CyrilleKarmann, It's not simplifying. Im expecting a fraction like 20/5 to go in and become 4. Or 18/4 to become 9/2.

Comment: I see, but what is it giving instead of the value you expect?

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann just the same fraction is outputted that is put in.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann CORRECTION:. input: 15/3, output: 3/3

Comment: Shouldn't `this.den = num / gcd();` be `this.den = den / gcd();` instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I see right away: You are dividing `num` by `gcd()` twice, for each of the numerator and denominator.  Also, once, you change the numerator, then the result of the call to `gcd()` may change.  Call "gcd" once, store its result, and use it later:

```
int gcd = gcd();
if (gcd > 1) {
   this.num = this.num / gcd;
   this.den = this.den / gcd;
}
```

Additionally, there are more efficient ways of obtaining the greatest common divisor: [Wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).  See Euclid's algorithm on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't quite understand the if(gcd). Should anything else be in the parentheses? THanks for the help.